# showing wordpress featured image in slider

Tags: wordpress

I want show featured image in my slider. so what i've done in my function.php is like below:

```
   <?php

   function revconcept_get_images($post_id) {
   global $post;

   $thumbnail_ID = get_post_thumbnail_id();

   $images = get_children( array('post_parent' => $post_id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order ID') );

    if ($images) :

      foreach ($images as $attachment_id => $image) :

          $img_alt = get_post_meta($attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); //alt
          if ($img_alt == '') : $img_alt = $image->post_title; endif;

          $big_array = image_downsize( $image->ID, 'large' );
          $img_url = $big_array[0];

          echo '<li>';
          echo '<img src="';
          echo $img_url;
          echo '" alt="';
          echo $img_alt;
          echo '" />';
          echo '</li><!--end slide-->';

    endforeach; endif; }
   ?>
            <div class="flexslider"> <!-- function called in index.php -->
                    <ul class="slides">
                   <?php revconcept_get_images("$post->ID"); ?>
                </ul>
            </div><!--end flexslider-->
```

Now i have two problem. no.1 My featured image is not showing in the slider. It's showing a broken link. but it can echo the post_id. no.2 I want show only 3/4 images from the latest post of cat=5. can anyone help me to do this ? note that i am using flexslider for my slider.

Comment: DId you try: `$thumbnail_ID = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id);`?

Comment: Just tried.. not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is what I've tested, you may want to refine the query a bit, but for me it worked. In `functions.php` put

```
function revconcept_get_images($post_id) {

    $images = get_posts( array(
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'hide_empty' => true,
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'orderby' => 'menu_order ID'
            ));

    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $image_url = $image->guid;
        $img_alt = get_post_meta($image->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); //alt

        echo '<li><img src="'.$image_url.'" alt="'.$img_alt.'" /></li>';

    }

}
```

And in index.php put (where you want)

```
<div class="flexslider"> <!-- function called in index.php -->
    <ul class="slides">
       <?php revconcept_get_images($post->ID); ?>
    </ul>
</div><!--end flexslider-->
```

If you want to show all featured images from posts you have just put `'posts_per_page' => -1,` in the `get_posts()` array.

Comment: Thanks for your support, your code is working for me now. can you tell me two more thing, that is how can i show only category = 4 post's images in the slider? and how can i make images in the slider link-able with the respective post. I am sorry for asking too many, i am newbie in wordpress & php.

Comment: If you want to filter images from certain category, you'll need to add to your query either `'cat' => #ID` where `#ID` is the id of the category you want to show, or either `'category_name' => 'name'` (using category name). Linking it shouldn't be that hard, since you have post id. Instead of current echo try `echo '<li><a href="'.esc_url(get_permalink($post_id)).'"><img src="'.$image_url.'" alt="'.$img_alt.'" /></a></li>';`